# React getInitialState not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to React and am trying to make a mortgage calculator while learning the basics of the framework. My question is, how can I fix the issue that when I change any of the input fields, the `rate` which is set by `getInitialState` to `2` disappears along with everything else and React no longer knows the state of `rate`. Thanks so much in advance!

```js
 
var MortgageCalc = React.createClass({
  mortgageCalc: function() {
    //findDOMNode to pull entered values into function   
    var principal = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.principal).value,
        rate = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.rate).value * 0.01,
        term = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.term).value * 12;
    var monthlyRate = rate/12;
    var factor = Math.pow(monthlyRate + 1, term);
    var numerator = monthlyRate * factor;
    var denominator = factor - 1;
    var quotient =  numerator/denominator;
    var payment = principal * quotient;
    console.log('$' + payment.toFixed(2));
    return payment.toFixed(2);
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
  
    return {value:{rate: 2}, payment: '0.00'}
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value, payment: this.mortgageCalc()});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <h2>Mortgage Calculator</h2>
        <form className="form-group">
          <input type="number" ref="principal" placeholder="Loan Amount" value={this.state.value.principal} onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
          <input type="number" ref="rate" placeholder="Interest Rate" value={this.state.value.rate} onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
          <input type="number" ref="term" placeholder="Length of loan" value={this.state.value.term} onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
          <h3>Your estimated monthly payment is ${this.state.payment}</h3>
        </form>        
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MortgageCalc/>, document.getElementById('form'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="form"></div>
```

Comment: `React.createClass` is a very old version that isn't supported anymore, not sure what tutorial you are using, but it is very outdated. You should work through the tutorials in the [official React docs](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#overview) to learn the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are saving `value` as a number instead of an object in your `handleChange` method:

```
handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value, payment: this.mortgageCalc()});
}
```

Should be:

```
handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
        value: { rate: event.target.value }, 
        payment: this.mortgageCalc()
    });
}
```

```js
var MortgageCalc = React.createClass({
  mortgageCalc: function() {
    // PUll values from state 
    var principal = this.state.value.principal,
        rate = this.state.value.rate * 0.01,
        term = this.state.value.term * 12;
    var monthlyRate = rate/12;
    var factor = Math.pow(monthlyRate + 1, term);
    var numerator = monthlyRate * factor;
    var denominator = factor - 1;
    var quotient =  numerator/denominator;
    var payment = principal * quotient;
    return payment.toFixed(2);
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      value:{
        rate: 2,
        principal: 30000,
        term: 2
      }, 
      payment: '0.00'
    }
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ payment: this.mortgageCalc() })
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: { 
        ...this.state.value,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value 
      }, 
      payment: this.mortgageCalc()
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <h2>Mortgage Calculator</h2>
        <form className="form-group">
          <input type="number" name="principal" placeholder="Loan Amount" value={this.state.value.principal} onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
          <input type="number" name="rate" placeholder="Interest Rate" value={this.state.value.rate} onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
          <input type="number" name="term" placeholder="Length of loan" value={this.state.value.term} onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
          <h3>Your estimated monthly payment is ${this.state.payment}</h3>
        </form>        
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MortgageCalc/>, document.getElementById('form'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="form"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. So that works for rate, but it makes the handleChange work exclusively for rate

Comment: @BrianRl Your `mortgageCalc` function needs some work. If you enter a loan amount AND years, you will see correct values being returned.

Comment: Looks like your code needs to have a length FIRST and then a loan amount to work.

Comment: The handleChange function you provided will only work for rate though, correct? Commenting on what you mentioned about adding amount and year, this is exactly my problem. If I use getInitialState to set all of the inputs, as soon as you change one of the numbers, all of the values inside the inputs disappear

Comment: Ah okay, you did not explain that very well in your question. I understand now and have fixed my example. Please run the code again and it should be working. I made changes to the inputs, the `mortgageCalc` function, `getInitialState` and I had to add a `componentDidMount`. Needed a lot of work to get it working like you wanted.